# Multiple AJAX posts to Web Service that returns value. Should I synchronize?

Tags: ajax, rest, posts, synchronize

My website is sending ajax posts to my web service, and the web service in return will return a json and that json will be further use in success callback.

Now, here's my problem, when my website is sending multiple ajax posts, it seems that those json that the web service returned gets jumbled up.

I'm thinking on synchronizing either the ajax posts or the web service (REST)?  I've read that you don't need to synchronize REST services, is that true?  If synchronizing is the solution, where should I synchronize it?  Will async: false in ajax synchronize the posts?

Thanks.

I thought about including some codes:

Web Service:

```
@POST
@Override
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Customer create(Customer cust){
    custManager.save(cust);
    return custManager.getCust(custManager.getCount());
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  url:  custURL,
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(sdata),
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(json){
     var cust = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
     var newId = cust.id;
     updateCustId(oldId, newId);
  }
});
```

What it does is it post to web service the data of the customer, and the web service designates an id for it and it return it to the client to update its customer id.  That's not it all, I'm also updating other tables that is reference to the old customer id to the new generated from server, and after updating these other tables, it also will be send to the web service. The tables I'm talking about is web sql, its queries too works asynchronously.  So end result is sometimes the ids got jumbled up and the other tables were send to the web service but the customerid it used is still the old one (I've used callbacks, ensured that it needed to be updated first before it will be sent to the server).

making my ajax calls async: false to make them synchronous and not get jumbled together works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is asynchrony, specifically. It sounds like you have some bug in your web-service implementation. What you describe should work fine.

Multiple Ajax requests are completely independent. Back end servers should treat each request separately.

You may have a problem way back in having data shared between threads on your web-application, which is causing problems with simultaneous access to the same data. If so this is the point to fix, and (in the worst case), put a mutex around just the small bit of code that is doing the cross-contamination.

If you find that data is leaving the server okay, but it is corrupted in your application, then the bug lies there.

I would strongly advise against trying to mask what sounds like a significant back-end bug by making a whole chunk of your app synchronous. Fix the underlying corruption issue, if that issue is caused by something that just cannot be made thread safe, then lock just that tiny bit.

Your question about REST is a bit irrelevant. REST services vs other architectures don't change whether code needs to be synchronous or not. When you use Ajax, you are using the HTTP protocol, which is intended to be asynchronous and stateless. A web-application of any style that requires synchronous access by clients is a big red flag of something wrong, in my view.

Beyond that general advice, you'll need to ask specific code-based questions for more detail.

Comment: Hi, I thought about what you said.  Everything works perfectly when I'm posting just one customer.  Here's the thing, when I post more than one, sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes the server that is supposed to return a json, returns null (for some customer).

Comment: Exactly - I suspect this is a bug with thread handling on your server, and is nothing to do with Ajax or Javascript. So making the front end synchronous would only mask your bug, not solve it. The behavior you suggest very strongly indicates that you should not try to patch your client to make the bug go away. It is like saying that your car engine backfires when you go over 30 mph, so you're considering cutting off half the accelerator pedal so you can't make it go that fast.

Comment: I heard ya. My server is created from the netbeans "create a web restful service from database" wizard, I've modified it a little to suit my needs.  You can see the code on my web service above in the question. Can you suggest how I can have a thread run on every request?? Thanks